# Get column names if value is true

Tags: sql, postgresql

Say I have table:

```
table_name: animal
column_names:
"dog": 'f',
"cat": 'f',
"cow": 't'
.
.
.
```

How can I display the column name "cow" ?

Thanks!

Comment: The question is a bit unclear, at least to me. Could you share some sample data and the result you're trying to get for it?

Comment: What does this mean? You have a table named animal with column_names (dog, cat, cow)? And these columns have values f,f,t? What is your problem? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Do you know what `SELECT` and `WHERE` are?

Comment: This sounds like a bad design to begin with You shouldn't have one column for each animal, but one column that contains the type of the animal. After all an animal can't be a cow and a dog at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Only simple way to do that - checking directly each column:

```
select 
  case 
    when dog=true then 'dog'
    when cat=true then 'cat'
    when cow=true then 'cow'
  end as col
from animal
```