# Insert a concat string based on multiple values in the table with delimiter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like this:

| id | value1 | value2 | value3 | string |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | true |  |  |  |
| 2 |  | true | true |  |
| 3 | true |  | true |  |

I am doing a transformation job to transform the above table into another one which will only have the string field, and the string values will be consists of the values + a "||" as delimiter if there are more than one value being true.

```
for id 1, string = "value1"
for id 2, string = "value2||value3"
for id 3, string = "value1||value3"
```

I want to do this operations in the select query inside the insert query, is that possible?

I thought of using temp variable but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/q/52556835/3917754

Comment: Just build a select which produces the results you want, then convert it to an insert. Once you've had a go at that, if you are still stuck, post your attempt for someone to help you with.

Comment: Storing similar value in multiple column in a table (the current table) OR storing multiple value in single column (the new table) are both bad design. You should reconsider

Comment: Build a select query using if else and dynamic sql and use that for insert . Let me know if any problems after that

Answer (score 0):

You could use `CONCAT_WS` and a bunch of `CASE` expressions

```sql
SELECT
    Id,
    CONCAT_WS('||',
        CASE WHEN value1 = 'true' THEN 'value1' END,
        CASE WHEN value2 = 'true' THEN 'value2' END,
        CASE WHEN value3 = 'true' THEN 'value3' END)
FROM YourTable t
```

Or you could unpivot and re-aggregate in a subquery

```
SELECT
    Id,
    (
        SELECT STRING_AGG(str, '||')
        FROM (VALUES(
            (value1, 'value1'),
            (value2, 'value2'),
            (value3, 'value3')
        ) v(val, str)
        WHERE val = 'true'
    )
FROM YourTable t
```